# OrmLite will not allow '@@' in postgresql query

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to add parameterised query using tsquery for postrgresql.

The raw postgresql looks like:

```
and search @@ 'john' ::tsquery;
```

Any time I try to add it to a query like:

```
query.And("search @@ 'john' ::tsquery");
```

It throws error that it is potentially unsafe fragment.

How do I allow this to pass validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use C# string.Format syntax for indexing db params in SQL Fragment queries, e.g:

```
query.And("search @@ {0}::tsquery;", request.SearchTerm);
```

You can use `UnsafeAnd` to bypass SQL Fragment validation

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work.  It seems anytime `@@` is in string it will not allow it even if I just put string in with interpolation

Comment: @Guerrilla You can use UnsafeAnd